# can an iso file be erased from a liveusb?

Tags: live-usb, system-installation

I have decided to install ubuntu alongside Mac OS X on my computer. I am wondering if the ubuntu installer ISO file can be erased from my USB after installation, and will be able to use my USB normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB flash drives are reusable devices that read and write to flash memory, a solid-state storage medium that's both inexpensive and durable. You can overwrite and/or reformat a USB flash drive multiple times, very many times indeed.